# Using LESS to recursively style an inner class of the same name?

Tags: javascript, css, less

I just started working with LESS but haven't been able to find an answer to this anywhere.

Can less support some sort of nesting or recursion for the same class?

My requirement is that I may have a div nested somewhere under another div of the same name (it won't necessarily always be a direct first level child of the parent div).

I need to style the 2nd div differently to the first... is this possible.

NOTE: I'm tied to using LESS due to the project I'm on so other frameworks are not an option.
I realize defining different classes for each div would work but also not an option.
I know this is a strange one but working within the limitations of the project I'm on unfortunately.

Comment: Without showing what you've tried (LESS used, what it compiles to, markup, etc.) and why it doesn't work the way it should, we can only guess what you actually mean.

Comment: I completely agree with @cimmanon on that, I merely explained some basic LESS behavior in my answer that may apply to your problem, but for help on your exact problems ... you need to give us some code ^_^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do it like this:

```
div.someClass {
    div.someClass {

    }
}
```

You will probably have to "reset" any original styles you no longer want within the nested div like this:

```
div.someClass {
    color: red;
    div.someClass {
        color: #333;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, that was my intuition but it does nothing when I try it. Would be the equivlent of div.someClass div.someClass {} in plain CSS but no luck.

Comment: Still no luck. What you say above sounds 100% but doesn't appear to work, I'm unsure if what I want is actually possible.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mtbottens/HQVz7/  Is this not what you need? You may need to show an example.

Comment: This is how I interpreted the question, and it appears to work expected.

Comment: Many many thanks... yes, I've tried you're demo and that's exactly it. Turns out the project is a mess... the stylesheets are huge. so even though this works, other parts of the stylesheet were completely over-riding even the nested classes I defined... so that's why it was not working for me. Accepting your answer as it is correct. Many thanks.

Comment: This makes sense, hope it is not too hard to get the whole stylesheet to work =) @user2355891 You get a +1 from me! For posting the answer first and for writing it in a very concise way ;-) I tend to get overexcited and try to explain everything ^_^ Bets!

Answer (score 3):

of course you can nest your selectors. Here is an example, if you want mydiv display differently if it is inside or outside the parent. `.mydiv` will display red if it is somewhere inside the `.outerdiv`, and red everywhere else on the page.

**LESS:**

```
.mydiv {
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
    background:green;
}
.outerdiv {
    width:300px;
    background:orange;
    .mydiv {
        background:red;
    }
}
```

the output **CSS:**

```
.mydiv {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background: green;
}
.outerdiv {
  width: 300px;
  background: orange;
}
.outerdiv .mydiv {
  background: red;
}
```

and the selector `.outerdiv .mydiv` will work on all object of class `.mydiv` inside the outerdiv, no matter the nesting leve.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6F7uY/)

and it should work the same with nesting **classes with the same name**, like so (I add some fanciness with the variable and calculation =)

**LESS:**

```
@width:300px;

.mydiv {
    height: 100px;
    width: @width;
    background: green;
    .mydiv {
        width:(@width - 100px);
        background:red;
    }
}
```

output **CSS:**

```
.mydiv {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  background: green;
}
.mydiv .mydiv {
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
}
```

The multileveled selector will automatically inherit the properties from the simple selector in the stylesheet.

### [DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/6F7uY/2/)

hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly as I needed. See my answer below as to why it wasn't working for me earlier. Much appreciated!